# No certificate at entry lib/armeabi-v7a/libtess.so

Tags: android, tesseract

I have just added Tesseract and Leptonica support to my project,now when I try to install the app on my device,it says:

```
PackageParser(377): Package com.blutechnologies.scancard has no certificates at entry 
lib/armeabi-v7a/libtess.so; ignoring!
```

I have checked my `libs` folder in my project and have found that it does not have arm-eabi while the `tess-two` library project which I imported has that in it's `libs` folder.

Comment: It sounds like the library got into the apk without being signed.  Did you modify the apk yourself?

Comment: Nope,just add the library,resolved errors...run